# Compass generated_images_dir is placing files in wrong folder

Tags: html, css, compass-sass

I have an issue with the compass generated_images_dir. The generated images doesn't get placed in the `css/img` directory but is instead placed in `css`. The goal is to have `img-sb11bbe84f2.png` inside `css/img`.

How can I get this to work?

I'm using ruby 2.1.2, compass 0.12.7 and Ubuntu 14.04 in case it's relevant

config.rb:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
generated_images_dir = "css/img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Compass watch output:

```
>>> Change detected at 23:12:08 to: print.scss
    create css/print.css 
    create css/ie.css 
    create css/img-sb11bbe84f2.png
    create css/screen.css 
>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

Output directory is:

```
css
├── ie.css
├── img
├── img-sb11bbe84f2.png
├── print.css
└── screen.css
```

Comment: read more here https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/857

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
generated_images_dir = "."
```